# Classic login window for Debian 6

Tags: debian

I installed the latest Debian onto a laptop, and I do not like the login list showing the users.  I used the gdm-manager tool to show users to false and that did not do the trick.  Any helps in this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to change the gdm theme to one that does not show users.

Comment: Changing the theme didn't work, but the Google search pointed me to the right page - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/change-login-theme-on-squeeze-878416/ - by allowing to find the proper conf file to uncomment.  gdm3-setup didn't do the trick, but this did.  thanks.